# AEP with a Twist!

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory

We know by AEP that if random variables $X_1,X_2,...$ are i.i.d. drawn from $P_X$ then the probability of the vectors in the weak typical set $$A_{\epsilon}^n = \{\vec x \in \mathcal{X}^n: |\frac{-1}{n}\log P(\vec x) - H(P_X)| \leq \epsilon \}$$
tends to 1. 
I am working on a slightly different problem. Random variables $X_1,X_2,...$ are independently drawn from $P^1_X,P^2_X,..,P^n_X$ respectively. Let use denote $\tilde P_X = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n P^i_X$ (ie, the average of the distributions). Is it true that the sum of the vectors contained in the set $B_{\epsilon}^n$ would have a very high probability?
$$B_{\epsilon}^n = \{\vec x \in \mathcal{X}^n: |\frac{-1}{n}\log P(\vec x) - H(\tilde P_X)| \leq \epsilon \}$$

$$ = \{\vec x \in \mathcal{X}^n: |\frac{-1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\log P^i_X(x_i) - H(\tilde P_X)| \leq \epsilon \}$$
I have no idea how to prove/disprove this. It seems like I can not use Weak law of large numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $X_n = n$ with probability $1$. Then $H(\tilde{P}_X) = \log n$, but the only vector with non-zero probability has $\frac{1}{n} \log \frac{1}{P(\vec{x})} = 0$.

Comment: I think the same answer is more insightful if you if define $X_n = n \mod N$ to restrict the random variables to finite symbols. $H(\tilde P_X) \approx \log N$ in that case. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Hey, I think the statement hols if I tweak it to $\frac{-1}{n}\sum \log \tilde P_X (x_i)$ in my definition of $B_{\epsilon}^n$